# What is the preferred way of showing/hiding buttons when hovering using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been thinking of a way to display certain controls (ie. buttons, links) at the end of a table row when I hover across the table row itself.  I came across this question:

[jquery specific show buttons on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933881/jquery-specific-show-buttons-on-hover)

He was embedding the HTML for the controls within his div.  Would it be more/less optimal to dynamically create the buttons using javascript on hover of the div instead?

I just want to know how everyone else does it.

Comment: Just how I do it: I always create the buttons at the HTML level and then show/hide them in the row onhover event handler. That seems to me easiest and cleanest all around.

Answer (score 2):

Since this effect can be nicely achieved without JavaScript, I'd skip JavaScript, and go to CSS+HTML. I take the code in the linked question as an example.

**Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/8U2HR/**

```
.product .show_on_hover {
    display: none;
}
.product:hover .show_on_hover {
    display: block;
}
```

This solution, using the [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3Ahover) is [supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t14) in all modern browsers (and IE7+), even when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: I understand the approach to using CSS and HTML only.  However, I'm designing a table with some rows.  When I hover over the row, the buttons actually appear outside the table, do you know what I mean?  It's like dangling at the end of the row outside the table.  My understanding is that I need javascript to calculate the width of the row and get the correct x, y coordinates to absolutely position my hanging div.  Would the CSS only solution be able to achieve this?

Comment: @Mark Can you show your example? I can guess for your intentions, but that might be wrong. It's easier to see your real code.